# SugarCRM C# set_relationshp

Tags: c#, rest, soap, sugarcrm

I am using SugarCRM v.6.5.16

Soap: http://{CRM Path}/service/v4_1/soap.php

I have been tasked to create a program that reads values from a JSON string to input into SugarCRM.

The object creation of Account, Contact, Opportunity etc. is working just fine. I am however unable to the the set_realtionship or set_realationships from the SOAP API to work.

If possible could someone give me a quick example of how to make this work.

I have found **very** **little** documentation regarding coding in C# and SugarCRM SOAP functions. I can directly insert into the 'link' table but would prefer to utilize the API since somebody took the time to write it.

If REST would work better than SOAP an example of that would also be useful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is with sights for the future recommended by Sugar to use REST. Advantages are that REST is faster than SOAP and REST will live longer in the product SugarCRM.